# Use nested functions with the cleanup attribute in C. (GCC compiler)

Tags: c, gcc

I am currently trying to break C a little in my free time. A thing I'd like to using the cleanup attribute to free a matrix based on the length of the first level.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void free2d(void * param,int inp){
    void ** unpacked=*((void ***)param);
    for(int i=0;i<inp;i++) free(unpacked[i]);
    free(unpacked);
}
#define BAKE_FREE2D(len) void wrapFree2dl##len (void * ptr){free2d(ptr,len);}
#define AUTOFREE(len) __attribute__((cleanup (wrapFree2dl##len)))
void main(){
    BAKE_FREE2D(5);
    int ** AUTOFREE(5) a=malloc(5*sizeof(void*));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) a[i]=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
}
```

This code works fine.

However what I'd like to do is devicing a macro that doesn't need the BAKE_FREE2D macro.
A thing I tried is using a "lambda expression" like `({void fct(void*ptr){free2d(ptr,5);};&fct})`.
However to use the cleanup attribute an identifier has to be create.
I am using the GCC-Compiler and have no intention of making such code portable for other compilers, so using compiler-specific syntax is an options and probably required.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to go for a similar language where these things are standardized? You'll find a lot more documentation on how to do it safely without resorting to "magic" if you do.

Comment: I am doing this as a side activity. If I were to really try and implement such a thing myself I would either write the code manually without the cleanup attribute or use a solution like the one I already posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
BAKE_FREE2D(5);
//          ^
int ** AUTOFREE(5) a=malloc(5*sizeof(void*));
//              ^           ^
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
//            ^
```

`5` everywhere. `2d` should be an object with constructor and destructor. Although this doesn't answer your question directly, consider the following design. By encapsulating the row count information into the object itself, it is passed with the pointer to the object to the free function.

```
struct matrix {
   int **d;
   size_t x, y;
};
struct matrix *matrix_new(size_t x, size_t y) {
   // blabla
}
void matrix_free(struct matrix *p) {
   // blabla
}
#define MATRIX_AUTOFREE()  __attribute__((__cleanup__(matrix_free)))
int main() {
   MATRIX_AUTOFREE() struct matrix *m = matrix_new(10, 5);
}
```

You may also be interested in exploring other "autocleanup in C" projects available on the net, like: https://github.com/aperezdc/autocleanup https://docs.gtk.org/glib/auto-cleanup.html .